# java.io.IOException: There are no more files Android Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, teamcity

I am trying to run a clean build using the gradlew using TeamCity for CI/CD. I have BuildAgent to run it with what I believe to have all the necessary sdks, and everything installed. The Build Agents are running in a container. Additionally, the TeamCity server is on a Windows 10 VM.

I try to run a clean build and it runs a few tasks, but then says:

```
java.io.IOException: There are no more files
```

I also got this error running it another time:

> Task :annotations:compileKotlin FAILED
>       :annotations:compileKotlin

```
Execution failed for task ':annotations:compileKotlin'. org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: There are no more files
```

Am I missing files in the BuildAgent? I'm not sure what the problem is as it runs no problem on my local machine.

Comment: Add `--stacktrace` to Gradle invocation to see full stacktrace. (and share with us so we can help)